# How to download/clone source code from Azure App Service to local machine using azure-cli/powershell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli, azure-appservice

I happened to check an article which explained on how to download Azure app service source code:

[How to download Azure App Service Source Code Download](https://medium.com/@michaelhenderson/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-azure-app-service-59c848752b0f)

I would like to have something similar to be achieved (leveraging azure-cli/powershell), but based on following order:

- Step 1: Download app service source code using azure-cli / powershell commands
- Step 2: modify source code (locally)
- Step 3: create a zip of source code (locally)
- Step 4: Stop app service using azure-cli / powershell commands (getting it ready for deployment)
- Step 5: Deploy the zip using azure-cli / powershell commands
- Step 6: Start app service once the deployment is succesfull

I was reading a lot about azure-cli in order to work with app service.  Most of the articles start with creating an app and in my case, I have to start with an existing (already deployed) app.  I couldn't find an article which actually shows on how to download/clone an existing app service on to local machine (other than using git endpoint).  In the above, "Step 1" itself is a major hurdle for me.

Also, in this scenario, I would like to avoid "git" (based clone/push/deployments) if at all possible.  No offence on using Git, but, just wanted to learn other available options.

If I can have (azure-cli/powershell) examples for Steps 1, 4, 5 and 6, they will help me learn quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your order is **not recommended**. For safety, developers would rarely publish the source code directly in most instances.

If you want to download your own project published to Azure already, the best way is using FTP, which you post with the [link](https://medium.com/@michaelhenderson/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-azure-app-service-59c848752b0f).

Just a reminder, even you could download the source code, as I said, it is the code compiled, which would cause some mess when you use it. So store you source code well to avoiding this situation.

Comment: Got it.  How about Azure functions?  Does Azure not store the source code?  If so, may I know the command to retrieve source to local machine?

Comment: It not depends on Azure, it depends on the developers to store the source code to Azure or not. Function app is same as Web app in this aspect.